# SharePoint Online - Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

This is my first attempt at this and I'm getting syntax errors. What I want is a column that has a conditional value based on another column "Probability".

I have tried a few variations with assistance from other question answers but cannot get it to work:

```
=IF([Probability]="High";1;IF([Probability]="Low";0.3;IF([Probability]="Med-High";0.8;0.6)))
```

High is 1, Low is 0.3, Med-High is 0.8 and Med-Low is 0.6

Keep getting "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported"
Can anyone help or recommend a site where I can learn how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF([Probability]="High",1,IF([Probability]="Low",0.3,IF([Probability]="Med-High",0.8,IF([Probability]="Med-Low",0.6,0))))
```

**OR** this:

```
=IF([Probability]="High",1,IF([Probability]="Low",0.3,IF([Probability]="Med-High",0.8,0.6)))
```

Set **The data type returned from this formula is:** to **Number**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`). For example: If you are using German language for your SharePoint site

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: thanks! it was the ;/, usage which confused me as I had based my first attempt on something I had found here!

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following formula.

=IF([Probability]="High","1",IF([Probability]="Low","0.3",IF([Probability]="Med-High","0.8","0.6")))

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked :)

Comment: Please remember to accept it as answer.